# Extremal values of Hermitian bilinear and quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ complex Hermitian matrix. I recall having read before that $\sup\left\{\left<Ax,y \right> \ : \ \| x\| = \| y\| = 1\right\} = \sup\left\{\left<Ax,x \right> \ : \ \| x\| = 1\right\}$. Is it also true that $\inf\left\{\left<Ax,y \right> \ : \ \| x\| = \| y\| = 1\right\} = \inf\left\{\left<Ax,x \right> \ : \ \| x\| = 1\right\}$? Thanks.

Comment: The last one is wrong. For $A=I$, the first infimum is negativ, the second one is positive. You forgot positive definiteness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1\leq ... \leq \lambda_n$ be the real eigenvalues.

The sup statement (possible taking real part) is correct precisely when $\lambda_n+\lambda_1\geq 0$ (sup over unit vectors):
$$\sup {\rm Re} \;\{\langle Ax,y\rangle \} = \sup \;\{\langle Ax,x\rangle \} $$

and the inf statement is correct precisely when $\lambda_1+\lambda_n\leq 0$.
$$\inf {\rm Re} \;\{\langle Ax,y\rangle \} = \inf \;\{\langle Ax,x\rangle \} $$

Comment: I am not sure. Isn't the first supremum simply the greatest singular value and the second one the greatest eigenvalue?

Comment: @user251257 There is an issue about complex versus real so I have edited a bit. But perhaps that is not what you had in mind?

Comment: it is hermitian. All eigen values are real